# Covariant Derivative and Del Operator

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, vector-fields

I have been writing the divergence of a vector field in spherical coordinates, and I know the transformation rules for the del operator and a vector. It's pretty easy to transform both of them into spherical coordinates with the help of the Jacobian. I have been trying to do the same stuff using covariant derivative and Christoffel symbols from General Relativity. I am using the following procedure:
$$\nabla_{\alpha}V^{\alpha}=\partial_{\alpha}V^{\alpha}+\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\alpha \beta}V^{\beta}$$
but I am getting different answers from both methods. I am trying to understand the intuition that why both answers are different? Christoffel Symbols encodes the information on how coordinates change from point to point. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: What transformation rule are you using for the del operator? Del is an operator and doesn't really transform in the same way so that's probably why you're getting different answers. The covariant equation you used is the correct one.

Comment: The del operator transforms like an object with a lower index. Right?

Comment: Incidentally, $\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^\alpha=\partial_\beta\ln\sqrt{|g|}$, so the RHS is also $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_\alpha(\sqrt{|g|}V^\alpha)$.